# what is the vb.net command that allows system calls to process?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I can't recall the command that lets VB release the processor so that system commands may run.  For example, if I am in a loop doing something, but a "textbox.text" was changed, it won't update on the screen while processing the loop.
Brain freeze?  Senior moment?

Does anyone know what I am asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Application.DoEvents the thing you're after?

Comment: Yes.  Really big brain fart on this end.  Thanks for the assistance.